# How do I convert x = [x_de,x_nu]; from matlab to python?

Tags: python, matlab

Given this line of matlab:

```
x = [x_de,x_nu];
```

**What is the equivalent in python?**

x_de and x_nu are both 3 by 9 lists of lists. For example:

```
x_de = [range(9), range(9), range(9)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python lists are concatenated with the `+` operator:

```
x = x_de + x_nu
```

This would concatenate "vertically".

I guess you're trying to concatenate horizontally. So you'd need to concatenate each sublist:

```
x = [a + b for a, b in zip(x_de, x_nu)]
```

**Example:**

```
x_de = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
x_nu = [[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]

print x_de + x_nu
print [a + b for a, b in zip(x_de, x_nu)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]
[[1, 2, 7, 8], [3, 4, 9, 10], [5, 6, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: Thanks!  This makes sense, and it appears to be producing a similar output as the matlab file.

Now we are off to debug the rest of the matlab->python conversion.